# How can I join columns with the same id

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, concatenation, asp.net-core-3.1

> I want to combine(sql join) columns with the same id. I want to list
>   more than one picture side by side.

**how can I do it? I want to combine columns with the same id but I have to list the pictures side by side**

**Multiple Class**

```
public class MultipleClass
        {
            public Article ArticleDetails { get; set; }
            public Images ImageDetails { get; set; }
            public Category CategoryDetails { get; set; }
            public User UserDetails { get; set; }

        }
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Article> articleNames = db.Article.ToList();
            List<Images> imagesNames = ımng.ImageListesiDatabase();
            List<Category> categoryNames = db.Category.ToList();
            List<User> userNames = db.User.ToList();

            var multipleTable = from a in articleNames
                                join b in imagesNames on a.ArticleId equals b.ArticleId into table1
                                from b in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join c in categoryNames on a.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId into table2
                                from c in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join d in userNames on a.UserId equals d.UserId into table3
                                from d in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new MultipleClass { ArticleDetails = a, ImageDetails = b, CategoryDetails = c, UserDetails = d };
            return View(multipleTable);       
        }
```

**View**

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr id="@item.ArticleDetails.ArticleId">
            <td>

                @item.ArticleDetails.Title
            </td>
            <td>

                @item.ArticleDetails.Date
            </td>
            <td>

                @item.ArticleDetails.ArticleHidden
            </td>
            <td>

                @item.CategoryDetails.CategoryName
            </td>
            <td>

                @item.UserDetails.UserName
            </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/Image/@item.ImageDetails.Image" style="max-width:100px;">
                </td>
```

[ScreenShot It is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB1MN.png)

Comment: you can use group by in your sql query

Comment: how ı will can,can you show me an example @kriss